# How to select a different language on a website with selenium

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium

This is an open site with tax information. I access the site, click on 'Abzüge', then the next page is in English. I try to change to German, however, I cannot locate the button. My current code is

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path-to-my-chromedriver/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.estv.admin.ch/estv/de/home/allgemein/steuerstatistiken/fachinformationen/steuerbelastungen/steuerfuesse.html')
elem1 = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Abzüge')
elem1.click()
de = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[4]/header/div/div[2]/div/button[1]')
de.click()
driver.close()
```

The Error is `NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/div[4]/header/div/div[2]/div/button[1]"} (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.102)`

I have also tried to find the button by class and by shorter xPaths, but I can never locate the button.

I also need to select some buttons in the main field. So I gave that a try as well, but it does not work as well. My code to select Whole of Switzerland, without changing to German, is

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="LOCATION"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]')
element.click()
```

I get the same error, `NoSuchElementException`.

How would I change the language on the webpage, and how would I select a button in the body?

Comment: Try this XPath `//nav[@class='nav-lang']//li[contains(., 'DE')]` to locate the language element.(Top right corner).

Comment: This did not get an Exception. Could you elaborate on your solution? However, it did not change the language (at least not visibly on the browser that selenium opened).

Comment: This is the XPath to get the element having the language code as `DE`. If you are able to identify the element change the `DE` to `IT` (as `DE` is default language) and then click on this element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code with XPath locator discussed in comments.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.estv.admin.ch/estv/de/home/allgemein/steuerstatistiken/fachinformationen/steuerbelastungen/steuerfuesse.html')

WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//nav[@class='nav-lang']//li[contains(., 'IT')]")))

print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//nav[@class='nav-lang']//li[contains(., 'IT')]").text)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//nav[@class='nav-lang']//li[contains(., 'IT')]").click()
```

Comment: If I do this on the actual site I want to change the language, `https://swisstaxcalculator.estv.admin.ch/#/taxdata/deductions`, then it does not work

Comment: I tried it with the actual webpage I wanted to change the language and using `/html/body/div/div[4]/header/div/div[2]/div/button[1]'` as XPATH for DE works. Then selecting 'Gesamte Schweiz' works accordingly `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="LOCATION"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]').click()`. Cheers

Comment: On this page its a button you can use XPath as `//button[@title='German']`

Comment: But i will suggest use dynamic XPath. XPath `[@id="LOCATION"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]').click()` might change in the future is someone add any tag in between.

Comment: This works too. Cheers. I have tried this XPath earlier, but without the WebDriverWait Method, it does not work. So need to wait for the elements to be loaded first.