# Click on a dropdown selection with Python Selenium

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to change the language on a [website](https://swisstaxcalculator.estv.admin.ch/#/taxdata/tax-scales) with selenium. This is the second time I have problems with this dropdown because they changed the website layout, earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63978165/how-to-select-a-different-language-on-a-website-with-selenium).
The website is in English, when I open with Selenium. I want to change it to German.
I can open the language tab, see code, then I try to use that object to click on the mat-list-item, but it does not work. Which button do I have to click to change the language?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path-to-my-chromedriver/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://swisstaxcalculator.estv.admin.ch/#/taxdata/tax-scales')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div[4]/header/div/div[2]/header-widget')))
print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div[4]/header/div/div[2]/header-widget').text)
listEle = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div[4]/header/div/div[2]/header-widget')
listEle.click()
```

And then I try to click on `Deutsch`, but none of these work. I have tried them separately.

```
listEle.find_element(By.XPATH, "//h4[text()='Deutsch']").click()
listEle.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Deutsch").click()
listEle.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div[4]/header/div/div[2]/header-widget//div/div/app-language/div/mat-card/mat-list/mat-list-item[1]/div/div[2]/h4').click()
listEle.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="language"]/mat-card/mat-list/mat-list-item[1]').click()
listEle.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div[4]/header/div/div[2]/header-widget//div/div/app-language/div/mat-card/mat-list/mat-list-item[1]/div/div[1]').click()
```

I have also tried it with `driver` instead of `listEle` with the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now did a workaround, I changed my Mac's settings to 'Deutsch'. Now everything is in 'Deutsch' from the start. So I don't have to change the language at all.

Answer (score 0):

If like I think the order of the language in the list doesn't change you can simulate press key ENTER to choose the Deutsch which should be in the first place of the list.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://swisstaxcalculator.estv.admin.ch/#/taxdata/tax-scales')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div[4]/header/div/div[2]/header-widget')))
print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div[4]/header/div/div[2]/header-widget').text)
listEle = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div[4]/header/div/div[2]/header-widget')
listEle.click()
listEle.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried it multiple times, similar to one of my other solutions, selenium clicks on the 'Login' Button.